# How to concatenate 2 arrays?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Is their any helper to concatenate 2 arrays? I mean an helper to add all the elements of array1 to the end of array2 ?

```
  array1: array of integer;
  array2: array of integer;
```

Comment: It's explained in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Concat)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fairly new Delphi (XE7 as per comments), you can just do it like this:

```
PROCEDURE Test;
  TYPE
    TIntArr     = TArray<INTEGER>;

  VAR
    A1,A2       : TIntArr;

  BEGIN
    SetLength(A1,20);
    SetLength(A2,30);
    A1:=A1+A2
  END;
```

ie. simple addition.

Comment: No, it's XE7 and later

Comment: Pre XE7 example was provided in the dupe...

Comment: No need to define a custom type.